# Align two Series based on the value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to align the data in two Series and identify the holes in each. I have a solution and I'm looking to see if there is a better way to do this.

Example

```
Series 1                  Series 2
A                         B
B                         C
D                         D

Output
A     
B     B
      C
D     D
```

My Solution

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = pd.Series( np.arange(3), index=['A', 'B', 'D'] )
y = pd.Series( np.arange(3), index=['B', 'C', 'D'] )
Z = pd.concat([x,y], axis=1)                            # Align by index
Z1 = Z[0].reset_index().rename({'index': 'x'}, axis=1)
Z1.loc[Z1[0].isna(), 'x'] = ''
Z2 = Z[1].reset_index().rename({'index': 'y'}, axis=1)
Z2.loc[Z2[1].isna(), 'y'] = ''
pd.concat([ Z1['x'], Z2['y'] ], axis=1)
```

Output

```
Out[67]:
   x  y
0  A
1  B  B
2     C
3  D  D
```

Answer (score 2):

Since these Series have A, B, C, D in the index, I'd prefer to return that rather than with these as the values:

```
In [11]: pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"x": x, "y": y})
Out[11]:
     x    y
A  0.0  NaN
B  1.0  0.0
C  NaN  1.0
D  2.0  2.0

In [12]: pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"x": x, "y": y}).isnull()
Out[12]:
       x      y
A  False   True
B  False  False
C   True  False
D  False  False
```

Comment: To reproduce OPs output: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"x": x, "y": y}).notna().pipe(lambda d: d.mul(d.index, axis=0)).reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: I like the idea of multiplying the boolean with the index.  For others 
```
'A' * True -> 'A'
'A' * False -> ''
```

Answer (score 1):

#### comprehension with `in`

```
xy = sorted(x.index | y.index)
pd.DataFrame(dict(
    x=[a if a in x.index else '' for a in xy],
    y=[b if b in y.index else '' for b in xy]
))

   x  y
0  A   
1  B  B
2     C
3  D  D
```

---

#### comprehension with `align`

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(
    zip('xy', map(lambda s: [k if pd.notna(v) else '' for k, v in s.items()], x.align(y)))
))

   x  y
0  A   
1  B  B
2     C
3  D  D
```

Comment: I like your `align`.   I stole it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `pd.factorize` and `union` indexes, then `pd.concat` new constructed `pd.Series` with indexes generated using `map`:

```
mapper = dict(zip(*pd.factorize(x.index.union(y.index))[::-1]))

pd.concat([pd.Series(x.index, x.index.map(mapper), name='x'), 
           pd.Series(y.index, y.index.map(mapper), name='y')], axis=1).fillna('')
```

Output:

```
   x  y
0  A   
1  B  B
2     C
3  D  D
```

Or we can use `pd.Index.to_series` instead of pd.Series constrcutor:

```
mapper = dict(zip(*pd.factorize(x.index.union(y.index))[::-1]))

pd.concat([x.index.to_series(x.index.map(mapper), name='x'), 
           y.index.to_series(y.index.map(mapper), name='y')], axis=1).fillna('')
```

Output:

```
   x  y
0  A   
1  B  B
2     C
3  D  D
```

---

## I like @piRSquared's use of `align` with `pd.Index.to_series`

Using @piRSquared idea for `align`, we can get this to a tidy one-liner:

```
pd.concat(x.index.to_series(name='x').align(y.index.to_series(name='y')), axis=1)\
  .reset_index(drop=True).fillna('')
```

Output:

```
   x  y
0  A   
1  B  B
2     C
3  D  D
```